# How do I get the dragon fruit achievement in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

There is no fruit jet pack. I can't get it. How do I get it? I looked at the jetpacks many times. There are none.

Answer (score 6):

As of Version 1.5, Halfbrick (the developers) have been **rolling inventory.**   The inventory of items to purchase will be different every week and completing the cycle in 22 weeks.

> Our new Jetpack Joyride update is jam-packed with content! We’ve added
>   a new vehicle, more jetpacks, several outfits and that’s just the
>   beginning! There’s still plenty to come thanks to our all-new rolling
>   inventory system which adds new content every week. Read on for all
>   the details!
>
> **How does it work?**
>
> All jetpacks and outfits, both new and old, are now on a giant loop.
>   There will always be a set number of items available for purchase and
>   these will be rotated on a weekly basis.
>
> As new items are added, others will be cycled out. These could be
>   completely new items or fan-favourites returning to the game. The
>   process continues until we’re back at the beginning.
>
> **What happens if I miss an item? Is it gone for good?**
>
> Nope! It’s important to note that no items have been permanently
>   removed from the game. Items which are currently missing will
>   eventually return as the cycle progresses.

[Source](http://halfbrick.com/jetpack-joyride/jetpack-joyride-1-5-rolling-inventory-faq/)

If you don't see it now, keep checking every week as new inventory will be in stock to purchase.

**Once the Fruit Jetpack is available in the store, purchase it (20,000 coins), have it equipped, ride Mr. Cuddles** and the achievement will pop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, comparing my iPhone 5 to my Windows 8 computer versions of Jetpack Joyride, my computer has the Fruit Jetpack, but my iPhone does not... This may only be a computer feature, but if you see this achievement on Game Center then it is probably the creators fault that must be fixed by them. Maybe post a review on the game about it and read others to see if anyone else is having similiar problems

Answer (score 0):

Well you see... Halfbrick has announced that the jetpacks are on a huge loop...meaning you can get different Jetpacks every Friday for purchase in the stash. Not sure when jetpack will be released but it shall be released in the next 22 weeks because that's how long the loop takes to release every jetpack. I am also needing this challenge so... I'm waiting on the fruit jetpack too. Hopefully they will release the jetpack soon. Be sure to save up 20,000 coins for the fruit jetpack and good luck accomplishing the achievement. ^_^